# Using PHP to Access a User's Webcam

Tags: php, drupal, video, webcam

I'd like to allow users to record videos directly from their webcam.
I haven't done much work with PHP but am stuck with it for this project.
We currently have a system in place for video uploading and encoding, but nothing to actually access a user's webcam.
How would you recommend I proceed?

Comment: check this out guys!! worked for me http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/

Comment: as an end user, I would feel very worried if I thought a web site could access my webcam. The privacy implications to this concept are scary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Webcams aren't available to HTML or JavaScript/DOM in any browsers that I know of, so you're going to end up dependent on some sort of plugin.  I'd recommend you start your search with Adobe Flash/Flex, though It's possible that Microsoft Silverlight is able to do the same thing.  Flex is a bit more reliable technology and has been around longer, but Microsoft is pouring a ton of money into Silverlight, and I expect it to improve radically over the next few years.

Comment: From what I've heard, Silverlight does not (at this time) allow access to mic's or web cams.

Comment: I've actually managed to do exactly this with Drupal.  Blogged about doing this at http://davidwees.com/myblog .

Comment: It sounds like the OP was asking about accessing the webcam on the end user's site, not streaming from a single webcam attached to the server.  However, Red5 is definitely an affordable option for streaming from the server side.

Comment: This information is outdated. Webcams can be accessed via JavaScript nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

You need client side technology -- PHP is server side. Check out Adobe Flash/Flex. I don't know anything about Microsoft Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [mugshot](http://drupal.org/project/mugshot) module on Drupal.org. It uses a flash widget to do the image capture, then saves the image as a node. Its code can almost certainly be mined for useful functions if you need to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The browser itself cannot access a user's webcam. There are proposals for a new type of input field to support this, but is is not currently available. You'd have to do it through a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to underlying hardware objects from a server side scripting language. If you are insterested into access to hardware devices so you have to use "browser components" like adobe flash , active X object, java applets, etc.