# Live Video Streaming with PHP

Tags: php, video, streaming

I have a PHP/AJAX/MYSQL chat application. I want to add video chatting to my application. How can I create live video streaming to be used for live video conferences/chatting in a PHP application. What are the key-terms I need to know if I wanted to build such a system? Is it a good idea in the first place to use PHP? Is there something I'm not thinking about? What other languages can I use, perhaps in conjunction with PHP?

Answer (score 20):

I am not saying that you have to abandon PHP, but you need different technologies here.

Let's start off simple (without Akamai :-)) and think about the implications here. Video, chat, etc. - it's all client-side in the beginning. The user has a webcam, you want to grab the signal somehow and send it to the server. There is no PHP so far.

I know that Flash supports this though (check this [tutorial on webcams and flash](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/webcam_motion.html)) so you could use Flash to transport the content to the server. I think if you'll stay with Flash, then [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) ([flex and webcam tutorial](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/22/displaying-a-webcams-video-in-a-flex-videodisplay-control/)) is probably a good idea to look into.

So those are just the basics, maybe it gives you an idea of where you need to research because obviously this won't give you a full video chat inside your app yet. For starters, you will need some sort of way to record the streams and *re-publish* them so others see other people from the chat, etc..

I'm also not sure how much traffic and bandwidth this is gonna consume though and generally, you will need way more than a Stackoverflow question to solve this issue. Best would be to do a full spec of your app and then hire some people to help you build it.

HTH!

Comment: Great Answer. If I want to transmit live tv what to do. can you suggest me?

Comment: I know its late, but there are things like ReactPHP

Answer (score 7):

> Please note that the below described service is no longer available as
>   it was based on FLV media (Flash)

This project which utilizes the Red5, Flex and PHP for Live Video Streaming and Recording has many features

1. Stream Live video to the viewers
2. Record the streams from your cam or other video input devices to the server
3. Preview the recorded streams and files and thumbnail the frame which you would like to display for the video.
4. Upload the videos from your computer and convert them to FLV which can be streamed using Red5 .
5. Choose from any resolutions
6. Can be plugged to any script
7. Each website user can have a separate Directory for storing their videos and thumbnails use this link
   http://code.google.com/p/red5-flex-streamer/

Answer (score 5):

PHP will let you build the pages of your site that make up your video conferencing and chat applications, but it won't deliver or stream video for you - PHP runs on the server only and renders out HTML to a client browser.

For the video, the first thing you'll need is a live streaming account with someone like akamai or the numerous others in the field. Using this account gives you an ingress point for your video - ie: the server that you will stream your live video up to.

Next, you want to get your video out to the browsers - windows media player, flash or silverlight will let you achieve this - embedding the appropriate control for your chosen technology into your page (using PHP or whatever) and given the address of your live video feed.

PHP (or other scripting language) would be used to build the chat part of the application and bring the whole thing together (the chat and the embedded video player).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

PHP/AJAX/MySQL will not be enough for creating the live video streaming application There is a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219476/using-php-to-access-a-users-webcam). It primarily suggests using Flex or Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

For live video conferencing you can't ignore the need of a streaming server.

Yes, flash will let you display video from a webcam within the local flash control, but that won't let you then send that video over the network - for that you need a streaming server to send it to.

If you're going to build something like this it's prudent to think about how you're going to host the video from a very early stage as it will influence how you build the application. Flash/Flex/Silverlight/Windows Media....etc....

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of "off-the-shelf" 'servers' that will run in your environment.
Most of these utilize the aforementioned Flex or Silverlight to implement the actual video itself but I'm pretty sure all will run under LAMP/PHP.

The challenges will picking the best software from everything that's available and getting your hosting-provider to let you stream video (it goes without saying that streaming is heavy on bandwidth).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782644/add-making-video-call-and-voice-call-to-my-site-php/12782932#12782932), quoted below

> I'm assuming you mean that you want to run your own private video
>   calls, not simply link to Skype calls or similar. You really have 2
>   options here: host it yourself, or use a hosted solution and integrate
>   it into your product.
>
> ---
>
> Self-Hosted
>   ----------------- This is messy. This can all be accomplished with PHP, but that is probably not the most advisable solution, as it is
>   not the best tool for the job on all sides. Flash is much more
>   efficient at a/v capture and transport on the user end. You can try to
>   do this without flash, but you will have headaches. HTML5 may make
>   your life easier, but if you're shooting for maximum compatibility,
>   flash is the simplest way to go for creating the client. Then, as far
>   as the actual server side that will relay the audio/video, you could
>   write a chat server in php, but you're better off using an open source
>   project, like
>   [janenz00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142004/janenz00)'s mention
>   of [red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/), that's already built and
>   interfacing with it through your client (if it doesn't already have
>   one). Or you could homebrew a flash client as mentioned before and
>   hook it up to a flash streaming server on both sides...either way it
>   gets complicated fast, and is beyond my expertise to help you with at
>   all.
>
> ---
>
> Hosted Service
>   ----------------- All in, my recommendation, unless you want to administer a ridiculous setup of many complex servers and failure
>   points is to use a hosted service like
>   [UserPlane](http://www.userplane.com/) or similar and offload all the
>   processing and technical work to people who are good at that, and then
>   worry about interfacing with their api and getting their client well
>   integrated into your site. You will be a happier developer if you do.