# Add making video call and voice call to my site php

Tags: php, video, video-streaming

I am creating a social network for some crowd.At there I need to add video calling and voice calling functionalities(like facebook or skype) to this site.I need to do this with PHP.Is there any api or help menu for this?

Comment: smells like a script request... have you tried google?

Comment: You will need to use more than just PHP...have you looked into the HTML5 video, you can connect to the connected webcam?

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="callto://+2345634563456">Link will initiate Skype call to number</a>

<a href="skype:username?call">Link will initiate Skype call to username</a>
```

Easy for Skype. Don't know about Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to run your own private video calls, not simply link to Skype calls or similar. You really have 2 options here: host it yourself, or use a hosted solution and integrate it into your product.

---

### Self-Hosted

This is messy. This can all be accomplished with PHP, but that is probably not the most advisable solution, as it is not the best tool for the job on all sides.
Flash is much more efficient at a/v capture and transport on the user end. You can try to do this without flash, but you will have headaches. HTML5 may make your life easier, but if you're shooting for maximum compatibility, flash is the simplest way to go for creating the client. Then, as far as the actual server side that will relay the audio/video, you could write a chat server in php, but you're better off using an open source project, like [janenz00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142004/janenz00)'s mention of [red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/), that's already built and interfacing with it through your client (if it doesn't already have one). Or you could homebrew a flash client as mentioned before and hook it up to a flash streaming server on both sides...either way it gets complicated fast, and is beyond my expertise to help you with at all.

---

### Hosted Service

All in, my recommendation, unless you want to administer a ridiculous setup of many complex servers and failure points is to use a hosted service like [UserPlane](http://www.userplane.com/) or similar and offload all the processing and technical work to people who are good at that, and then worry about interfacing with their api and getting their client well integrated into your site. You will be a happier developer if you do.

Answer (score 0):

For a video call to work, you will need:

1. A client program which can detect the webcam and mic from your system and upload (stream) to a server.
2. A streaming server, which will capture the uploaded stream and relays it to the other users- red5, Wowza, Fashmedia server etc.

Looks like you are a beginner in this area. If so, try with [red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/), since it is opensource. They have examples of video calling.