# building live stream video? chat video?

Tags: php, html, video-streaming, live-streaming, livechat

I was wondering how live streaming or chat video works? I know a bit about PHP and I've been learning ajax and jquery. I was wondering if it is possible to build such a system using PHP? Or maybe HTML5? I'm not too familiar with HTML5 but if that could be a possibility, I would definitely learn it.

Can someone help me get my feet going?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223983/live-video-streaming-with-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219476/using-php-to-access-a-users-webcam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HTML5, you're looking for WebRTC. See http://www.webrtc.org/. 
This spec enables live streaming (video/audio) from within a browser.

Still, you need a backend to process the streams and connect people together. This is not very well suited for PHP, and I'd rather use Node.js, a server that enables very lightweight 'two-way connections' to clients. See http://nodejs.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Open Tok](http://www.tokbox.com/), it might provide what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ffmpeg and ICECAST server along with php.
download and install ICECAST server. It works for windows and ffmpeg and lets you live stream a video in mp4 and webm which you can publish and showcase online with html and php. Its the easiest way. I wish someone had told me this but I had to figure this out, thru trial and error. If this doesn't work for you type live stream server software on google search engine. http://icecast.org/ code that should configure it with ffmpeg https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.4/icecast_8c_source.html. ffserver does no work for windows and its a huge waste of time.